# chrony time server cannot synchronize with time servers from the internet

Tags: time, chrony

My chrony time server with the version: 3.5-6ubuntu6.2, can get the time from another internal time server but not from time servers on the Internet. Could you please help me to synchronize my chrony server with a time server from the internet?

The working internal ntp time server can synchronize with the Internet

```
systemctl status ntp
● ntp.service - Network Time Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running)
```

But the chrony time server can't do it
I restarted the network and checked that chrony is online:

```
netplan apply
chronyc online
200 OK
```

The chrony service is running

```
systemctl status chrony
● chrony.service - chrony, an NTP client/server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/chrony.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-12-28 09:59:58 CET; 11min ago
       Docs: man:chronyd(8)
             man:chronyc(1)
             man:chrony.conf(5)
```

The connection to the internet is possible

```
telnet www.google.de 80
Trying 216.58.212.163...
Connected to www.google.de.

nc -zvu ptbtime1.ptb.de 123
Connection to ptbtime1.ptb.de 123 port [udp/ntp] succeeded!
```

This is the config of the chrony server

```
nano /etc/chrony/chrony.conf


pool pool.ntp.org iburst

server 192.53.103.108 iburst

pool 2.pool.ntp.org iburst

server 0.de.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.de.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.de.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.de.pool.ntp.org iburst


pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 2
```

Chrony recognises that there are soruces

```
chronyc activity
200 OK
28 sources online
0 sources offline
10 sources doing burst (return to online)
0 sources doing burst (return to offline)
0 sources with unknown address


chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 9
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? ptbtime1.ptb.de               0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? static.133.158.47.78.cli>     0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? alpha.rueckgr.at              0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? stratum2-2.NTP.TechFak.N>     0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? totoro.ax86.net               0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 195.50.171.101                0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 82.165.77.164                 0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 79.133.44.136                 0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp1.radio-sunshine.org       0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
```

But chrony does not synchronise

```
chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : 00000000 ()
Stratum         : 0
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
System time     : 0.000000009 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 0.379 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 1.000000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 1.000000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised
```

**What can I do to synchronize chrony with a server from the internet?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrony time synchronization problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/1047157/chrony-time-synchronization-problems)

Comment: No. The problem with the link is synchronization within a cluster. The problem with this question is that the Chrony time server cannot connect to the internet.

Comment: This was a firewall issue.